# Check if the path exists in Databricks

Tags: python, databricks, azure-databricks, dbutils

I try to check if the path exists in Databricks using Python:

```
try:
  dirs = dbutils.fs.ls ("/my/path")
  pass
except IOError:
  print("The path does not exist")
```

If the path does not exist, I expect that the `except` statement executes.
However, instead of `except` statement, the `try` statement fails with the error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: GET ...
ErrorMessage=The specified path does not exist.
```

How to properly catch `FileNotFoundException`?

Answer (score 2):

here is alternative

```
import os
dir = "/dbfs/path_to_directory"

if not os.path.exists(dir):
  print('The path does not exist')
  raise IOError
```

Answer (score 1):

This approach should work, and looks familiar with your code:

```
  try:
    dbutils.fs.ls(path)
    pass
  except Exception as e:
    if 'java.io.FileNotFoundException' in str(e):
      print('The path does not exist')
    else:
      raise
```