# Pyspark Delta lake Catching Table is not a delta table exception

Tags: exception, pyspark, databricks, filenotfoundexception, delta-lake

```
try:
    df1=spark.read.format("delta").load("/abc")
except Exception as ex:
  print(ex)
```

its giving exception as '/abc' is not a Delta table.;

I want to perform a specific operation when the file is not found.
Is there a class already available to catch it separately like FileNoTFoundException - which doesn't seem to work here.

Answer (score 1):

In pyspark 3.x, a nonexisting table will throw the generic [pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/utils.html).
This is translated from the Java/Scala layer. Unfortunately there doesn't exist an exception specific to "File Not Found".

```
from pyspark.sql.utils import AnalysisException

try:
    spark.read.format("delta").load("/abc")
except AnalysisException as ex:
    print(ex)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60311267/7052307 This one Worked for me